# How to search and display the fields from a table in an editor widget using progress 4gl

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Accept a customer number and then output the details of each order and items  to an editor widget.
Here customer , order ,order-line and items are table names.
where as customer and order tables have cust-num as common field , order and order-line(table-name) and order have order-num as common field , order-line and item have item-num as common field.
now i have to use a fill-in (f1 is object name) to get the cust-num and use a search button (search1 as object name) to find the corresponding fields and  display them in the editor widget ( editor-1 as object name).

```
define temp-table ttcustomer
field custnum like customer.cust-num
field cname like customer.name
field orders like order.order-num
field items like item.item-num
field itemname like item.item-name .


 find first customer WHERE customer.cust-num = input f1 NO-LOCK .

    create ttcustomer . 

      assign
      ttcustomer.custnum = customer.cust-num
      ttcustomer.cname     = customer.name. 



   for each order WHERE Order.cust-num = input f1  NO-LOCK .

      assign
      ttcustomer.orders   = order.order-num.

      for each order-line where order-line.order-num = order.order-num no-lock.


         for each item where item.item-num = order-line.item-num no-lock.

         assign 
         ttcustomer.items = item.item-num
         ttcustomer.itemname = item.item-name. 
         end.
      end.
    end.
```

i have written this code in search button . 
how can i display the temp-table ttcustomer in editor widget please help me :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After searching in a database how to display the result field values in an editor widget using progress 4gl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837622/after-searching-in-a-database-how-to-display-the-result-field-values-in-an-edito)

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better off using a browser instead of an editor. But if you are going to use an editor, this should give you what you need:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE edData AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

FOR EACH ttcustomer:
    edData = edData + ttcustomer.items + ", " + ttcustomer.itemname + CHR(10).
END.

editor-1:SCREEN-VALUE = edData.
```

The editor is just text so you won't be able to do any record selection/manipulation like you can with a browser. And if you have many ttcustomer records, you run the risk of overflowing the 32k character string size limit.