# After searching in a database how to display the result field values in an editor widget using progress 4gl

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Accept a customer number and then output the details of each order and items to an editor widget. 
Display them in the editor widget ( editor-1 as object name).

```
define temp-table ttcustomer
field custnum like customer.cust-num
field cname like customer.name
field orders like order.order-num
field items like item.item-num
field itemname like item.item-name .


find first customer WHERE customer.cust-num = input f1 NO-LOCK .

create ttcustomer . 

  assign
  ttcustomer.custnum = customer.cust-num
  ttcustomer.cname     = customer.name. 



 for each order WHERE Order.cust-num = input f1  NO-LOCK .

  assign
  ttcustomer.orders   = order.order-num.

  for each order-line where order-line.order-num = order.order-num no-lock.


     for each item where item.item-num = order-line.item-num no-lock.

     assign 
     ttcustomer.items = item.item-num
     ttcustomer.itemname = item.item-name. 
     end.
  end.
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you would want to display that on an editor. So I'll assume you want to concatenate the info you gathered in the for each loop into an editor.
So after the last end, you could do this:

```
define variable editor-1 as character view-as editor.
for each ttcustomer:
    assign editor-1 = editor-1 + ttcustomer.items + ' ' + ttcustomer.itemname + chr(13). 
end.
display editor-1.
```

If chr(13) doesn't work to skip a line, try chr(10). 
PS: An editor is really probably not the widget you want to display this. I'd use a browse. But since the question asks for an editor, there. 
PS2: You didn't assign the other fields you put on the temp-table, so I'm not displaying them. But it's just a matter of adding them to the assign line above, not forgetting the spaces, dashes or whatever you'd like to use as a separator.

Comment: i tried using the code which you told , but i am getting error as unable to update ttcustomer  table , where as i am only trying to assign .

Comment: I was re-reading your code. You need to understand how Progress syntax and commands work a little better before you can do this.
First, your create ttcustomer at the top creates one record. All your subsequent assigns inside the for each order loop are overwriting whatever value you had before. Same on the items, you'll end up with ONE record, no matter how many you're cycling in your loop.
Study a little about temp-tables, then information concatenating. If possible, follow some tutorials or formal training, it will help you a lot.